# Animated Pie Chart in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, tween

i'm trying to make an animated pie chart in AS3, which it only shows a single var, but this var updates every X seconds. What I wanna do, it's to animated this pie chart to update to the new "status" with a tween animation. Something I can't make work. I already tried with tweenmax and such.

This is my pie chart code generator:

```
var degree: Number = 90; 
var degChange: Number = 1; 

var circleR: Number = 100; 
var circleX: Number = 100; 
var circleY: Number = 100;
var angleR: Number = circleR / 4; 

var spBoard: Sprite = new Sprite();
spBoard.x = circleX;
spBoard.y = circleY;
C1.Maskmc.addChild(spBoard);


var shFill: Shape = new Shape();
shFill.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
shFill.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
shFill.graphics.lineTo(circleR, 0);
shFill.x = 0;
shFill.y = 0;

var shAngle: Shape = new Shape();

spBoard.addChild(shFill);

function updatePicture(t: Number): void {
    var radianAngle: Number //=// t * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var i: int;

    shFill.graphics.clear();

    shFill.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);

    shFill.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1);

    for (i = 0; i <= t; i++) {

        shFill.graphics.lineTo(circleR * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180), -circleR * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180));
        trace(i)
    }

    shFill.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);

    shFill.graphics.endFill();
}



var clockTimerTRas: Timer = new Timer(1000, 0);
clockTimerTRas.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, UpdateP);
clockTimerTRas.start();


function UpdateP(evt: Event): void {

    var TurnoEstaHora
    var TurnoActual_A: int = (it takes a var from a php here)
    degree = TurnoActual_A * (11.305)
    updatePicture(degree);

}
```

Which as i said before, it only makes a circle or incomplete circle depending on the var that loads from the PHP.

So far it works something like this, https://media.giphy.com/media/qiutE2wCo1YXe/giphy.gif

I wanna tween that animation. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;


var tempSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(tempSprite);
tempSprite.x = 100;
tempSprite.y = 100;


function convertAngleToRadians(angle:Number):Number
{
    return angle  / 180 * Math.PI;
}

function fillRound(
    graphics:Graphics,
    color:uint = 0x000000,
    alpha:Number = 1,
    radius:Number = 10,
    startAngle:Number = 0,
    endAngle:Number = 360,
    angleStep:Number = 1):void
{
    var tempRadians:Number;
    var startRadians:Number = convertAngleToRadians(startAngle);
    var endRadians:Number = convertAngleToRadians(endAngle);
    var radiansStep:Number = convertAngleToRadians(angleStep);


    var tempPoint:Point;


    graphics.beginFill(color, alpha);

    if (endAngle % 360 == startAngle % 360)
    {
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);

    }else
    {
        var pointsCount:Number = Math.ceil((endAngle - startAngle) / angleStep);
        for (var pointIndex:int = 0; pointIndex <= pointsCount; pointIndex++)
        {
            tempRadians = startRadians + pointIndex * radiansStep;

            tempPoint = new Point();
            tempPoint.x = Math.cos(tempRadians) * radius;
            tempPoint.y = Math.sin(tempRadians) * radius;

            graphics.lineTo(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y);
        }
    }

    graphics.endFill();
}

var _curPieStep:Number = 0;
function get curPieStep():Number
{
    return _curPieStep;
}
function set curPieStep(value:Number):void
{
    _curPieStep = value;

    drawPie();
}

var pieMaxStep:int = 30;
var pieAngleStep:int = 360 / pieMaxStep;
function drawPie():void
{
    tempSprite.graphics.clear();
    fillRound(tempSprite.graphics, 0xFF0000, 1, 100, 0, pieAngleStep * curPieStep);
}

var myTween:Tween = new Tween(this, "curPieStep", Bounce.easeOut, 0, pieMaxStep, 4, true);
```

You may just copy'n'paste it into Flash IDE and check the result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but as you can see that's exactly what I already have, it will update with a new "size" without tween.

Comment: I'm really sorry I've missed the fact that your code is almost the same. I've just edited my answer and added a tween there. Please, check it. Although, I would recommend use other Tween engine (not native Tween).

Comment: Thank you!! That's exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: I've another little issue I can't solve, I need to update this "tween" every x seconds, I tried with a timer and nesting everything inside a function but it won't work. I also tried just using the timer on the tween, and I didn't work. I tried a few other things and nothing. Would you give me a hand with that? The circle is supposed to change everytime the var pie AngleStep change.

Comment: Am I right that you want to repeat the tween every X seconds? Or you want to "update/go to the next step of tween" once per X seconds (e.g. the whole tween should be done in 10 sec, and you want to redraw an update every 1 second)? Which one from the 2 cases is yours?

Comment: Yeah, actually lets say the I load a var and its 360 the circle would be complete, but after an update (lets say every 10 seconds) the var changes to 280, I need to go from the 360 point to the 280 point. This var will change or stay the same every 10 seconds. And it would be great if I can just draw the circle from its latest point. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I get it. Unfortunately, the task is sort of complex and it depends on the other code you have. In general, I would suggest you just to stop the last tween and to create another tween from the last *curPieStep* to the new one. Also, maybe it woul be better for you to change the code and not to use *curPieStep*. Maybe it would be better to use tween for changine a variable that holds the value of angle for a pie chart.

Comment: Oh ok, if it is complex to you, it's impossible to me haha. All I can think of, it's to put everything inside a function, and redo it everytime I need it. But I can't find a way to put SET and GET function inside another one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var degree: Number = 90; 
var degChange: Number = 1; 

var circleR: Number = 100; 
var circleX: Number = 100; 
var circleY: Number = 100;
var angleR: Number = circleR / 4; 

var spBoard: Sprite = new Sprite();
spBoard.x = circleX;
spBoard.y = circleY;
C1.Maskmc.addChild(spBoard);


var shFill: Shape = new Shape();
shFill.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
shFill.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
shFill.graphics.lineTo(circleR, 0);
shFill.x = 0;
shFill.y = 0;
shFill.graphics.clear();

    shFill.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);

    shFill.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1);

var shAngle: Shape = new Shape();

spBoard.addChild(shFill);

function updatePicture(t: Number): void {
    var radianAngle: Number //=// t * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var i: int;
 i = clockTimerTRas.currentCount ;
      shFill.graphics.lineTo(circleR * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180), -circleR * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180));
        trace(i)
}


var TurnoActual_A: int = (100) ;

var clockTimerTRas: Timer = new Timer(10, TurnoActual_A);
clockTimerTRas.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, UpdateP);
 clockTimerTRas.start();


function UpdateP(evt: Event): void {

    var TurnoEstaHora

    degree = TurnoActual_A * (11.305)
    updatePicture(degree);

}
```

Comment: wow! Thank you! I was trying so hard to making it work with a tween library, I didn't even thought of that. You rock!

Comment: the "for " statement run so fast that the eye can't recognize the "enterframe " is much better. Good luck